# Custom Gravatar in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have displayed the gravatar as described in the Ruby on Rails book, the code of which is given below:

```
def gravatar_for(user)
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

But i want to add my own gravatar , means my own image from my local hard disk , similar to displaying image by specifying the url path. So, is there any ways of completing this task?

Comment: What was the reason of downvoting ? . i got the answer below and i am cleared now of the concept. So instead of downvoting people's questions please care to answer it. It would help them greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display your image from local hard drive via gravatar you have to upload it to gravatar webpage. 
If you want to display a image from your local drive without gravatar just add image to project (assets/images) and use:

```
image_tag('yourimage.jpg')
```

Comment: thnx for ur help . i got the answer :)